# Ask dnsmasq the hostname used to find to an IP address

Tags: dns, ip, dnsmasq

I know I can find a DNS name from an IP address by using a reverse translation DNS query.  But that just gives me **a** DNS name for that IP.  Instead, I'd like to find **the** DNS name that was used to find that IP address.  I understand that in general this is impossible, but it seems like I should be able to ask my `dnsmasq` server to give me the recent DNS queries, or interject some other DNS proxy to trace the lookups or something.

So, how would I go about finding which DNS hostname was used to get a given IP address?

Comment: Simple: Log all DNS requests.

Comment: And this is important.. why?  You can correlate if the DNS name is under your control as suggested by @techie007, but it's a lot of trouble.

Comment: @techie007: I guess my question is "how do I log all DNS requests", then.